# content div with -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch gives troubles with absolute positioned childrens on IOS devices

Tags: html, css, ipad, overflow

We're bussy programming a webapplication for tablets.

In this application we have a main content div where our contents are placed, some pages / slides have more content than the viewport allows so we added the following CSS to the content div;

```
#canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.absoluteElement {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="canvas">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="absoluteElement">This is absolute!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly on the iPad and desktop, but we have some problems with absolute or fixed placed children elements. When we scroll a page on the iPad, the absolute placed elements are also moving on the iPad until we untouch the screen (than it goes back to the absolute positioned position), but not on the desktop (as it should). This only happens when we enable the -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch option. When we disable this option the problems are gone on the iPad but the scrolling itself is verry slow and hitchy.

For your information, the absolute placed elements (.absoluteElement, should be absolute to the #canvas div, not to content).

How can we solve this easlily?